# Update/merge dataframe row only with non NA values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have these data frames:

```
original = data.frame(id = 1, paramA = 12, paramB=30)
update = data.frame(id=1 , paramA = NA , paramB = 22)
```

How can I produce this data frame:

```
result_df = data.frame(id = 1, paramA = 12, paramB=22)
```

In essence, the update data frame must update the `original` data frame, but only on the columns that are not `NA`. That's why `paramA` remained 12 and only `paramB` got updated to 22 from 30. The data frames will always have only 1 row. I tried searching for similar questions but I did not find something that fits this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could update `original` at non-NA places from `update` like

```
original[!is.na(update)] <- update[!is.na(update)] 

original
#  id paramA paramB
#1  1     12     22
```

Comment: I knew this could be easily and elegantly solved. Thank you!